# XPATH to copy node value from preceding element

Tags: xslt, xpath

I was hoping to get help on the XPATH I'm trying to create.

I have the following file structure in XML:

```
<Request>
    <RequestArea>
        <SourceText>**Text 1**</SourceText>
    </RequestArea>
    <ResponseArea>
        <TargetText></TargetText>
    </ResponseArea>
</Request>
<Request>
    <RequestArea>
        <SourceText>**Text 2**</SourceText>
    </RequestArea>
    <ResponseArea>
        <TargetText></TargetText>
    </ResponseArea>
</Request>
```

I need to copy value of **SourceText** node and paste it into following **TargetText** node.

So, the resulting XML file would be this:

```
<Request>
    <RequestArea>
        <SourceText>**Text 1**</SourceText>
    </RequestArea>
    <ResponseArea>
        <TargetText>**Text 1**</TargetText>
    </ResponseArea>
</Request>
<Request>
    <RequestArea>
        <SourceText>**Text 2**</SourceText>
    </RequestArea>
    <ResponseArea>
        <TargetText>**Text 2**</TargetText>
    </ResponseArea>
</Request>
```

I have the following XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="TargetText">
    <ResponseText>
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding::SourceText"/>
    </ResponseText>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the XSL engine (MSXSL) copies **Text 1** value into both subsequent **TargetText** nodes instead of using each following **SourceText** value as a source for the content that gets copied:

```
<Request>
    <RequestArea>
        <SourceText>**Text 1**</SourceText>
    </RequestArea>
    <ResponseArea>
        <TargetText>**Text 1**</TargetText>
    </ResponseArea>
</Request>
<Request>
    <RequestArea>
        <SourceText>**Text 2**</SourceText>
    </RequestArea>
    <ResponseArea>
        <TargetText>**Text 1**</TargetText>
    </ResponseArea>
</Request>
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the second template in your XSLT with

```
<xsl:template match="ResponseArea/TargetText">
    <ResponseText>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../RequestArea/SourceText"/>
    </ResponseText>
</xsl:template>
```

If you need the element to be named `TargetText` like in your desired example output instead of `ResponseText`, just change it.

The output of the above code is:

```
<Request>
    <RequestArea>
        <SourceText>**Text 1**</SourceText>
    </RequestArea>
    <ResponseArea>
        <ResponseText>**Text 1**</ResponseText>
    </ResponseArea>
</Request>
<Request>
    <RequestArea>
        <SourceText>**Text 2**</SourceText>
    </RequestArea>
    <ResponseArea>
        <ResponseText>**Text 2**</ResponseText>
    </ResponseArea>
</Request>
```